# Can I set a macro to delete media from a particular Whatsapp group or contact?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, whatsapp-messenger, automation

Is it possible to set up a macro using *[Macro Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en), [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)*, or any other automation app which will delete all the media received from a particular Whatsapp group or from some specific contacts.

I am running *Android 6.0 Marshmallow* on a non-rooted *Asus Zenfone 2 ZE551ML* with stock ROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible

Quoting MacroDroid developer, in future request (dated 21 Feb this year- you can access that from within the app in *forum* )

> WhatsApp has no SDK/API by design, they don't want third party apps interacting with their service.

When the automation app can't interact with WhatsApp, it obviously cannot set up automation tasks

I am not conversant with Tasker, but the limitation should be equally valid for any automation app

Comment: Incidentally, I have been trying to automate something similar and didn't succeed, because manipulating media also can't be done. Media in WhatsApp can't be backtracked to the sender, except by time stamp and in a busy group, you will have same time stamps for media sent by different people