# WhatsApp Android: Auto move images

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, images

Is there any way to automatically move images from different person to different folders?

Comment: [Related](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/170294/131553). WhatsApp uses own ways which are not exposed to other methods of automation , so I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 0):

No. But WhatsApp does manage images for you. You can see all images posted in a particular chat by clicking on the Name of the group or person.